# Is it possible to make a custom button for "Log in to Community as" a Contact?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, custom-button, customer-community

I know this is an out of the box functionality in Salesforce if you have Communities enabled, but can this be exported to another place in LEX?

For example, if I display portal users in an HTML table in an Aura Component, can I have one button per row be a custom "Log in as" button?

If there a method somewhere that you can feed in a Contact ID and then log in to the community as them (implying you have Manage External Users)?

Comment: This is a wild guess but if you look at the address bar as you click the button to log in as a community user you will probably see it change a bunch of times. Itll be hard but if you can capture the URLs it changes to you might be able to find the correct url with the correct parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the following URL when I click on the button:

---

https://{**yourdomain**}.my.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.su?oid={**orgId**}&retURL=%2F{**contactId**}&sunetworkid={**networkId**}&sunetworkuserid={**userId**}

---

You should be able to use the same URL as the standard button and fill in the appropriate values/variables. I was able to copy and paste it into a separate tab/window and get into the community as the user